# Scaffold-DbContext runs successfully but does not create any models

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using Visual Studio community edition 2022 and trying to update my Models from database in EntityFrameworkCore 6 (I added new tables and modified some). When I run the `Scaffold-DbContext` command, it runs successfully but does not produce any updates (or new classes) for the models. It created the models the first time, for that I had to add the following in the `.csproj` file.

```
<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
```

In the `<PropertyGroup>` element. When I run it now (for update) it builds and runs successfully but doesn't produce any updates to the models.

I am running the following command in the package manager console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=ccWebDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=*****" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context DataContext -f
```

When I run this command, I get the following output

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.
Unrecognized command or argument 'C#'
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Double-check your package versions to make sure they're all up to date. Also try with `-Verbose` to see if it give any additional clues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no -f option.

Did you mean -Force ?

Comment: Yes, -Force, but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Maybe some special characters in usename or password?

Comment: Nope, I have obviously masked the username and password here

Answer (score 0):

Check out your db users permission. If you have only read permission, it could not be enough. If you can have admin role, try with admin permission.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnerC.png)